# Flex Combobox and DateField Weird Bug

Tags: apache-flex, combobox, datefield

Using Flex 4.1 Build 16076

I have an mxml file, containing a textinput, a button, a datefield and a combobox.

The data provider for the combobox is an arraycollection.

When the flex application is started, the combobox's dropdownlist shows up fine. The calendar also displays when clicking on the calendar icon on the datefield.

Now when I click on the button which displays a popup window, and get the data from there and put it back on the textinput, combobox (select the item) and datefield, the combobox and the datefield does not show the dropdownlist and the calendar respectively.

I am not changing the data on datasource on the combobox. Merely selecting the item based on what was retrieved from popup window.

This one is really stumping me. Seems that the datefield and combobox does not respond to mouseevent. When the focus is on the combobox, I could still use the keyboard to change the values displayed, but the dropdownlist still does not show.

Has anyone encountered this behavior?

Comment: That is a strange bit of behavior are you positive you have the flash player debug version installed, it sounds to me like an error is occurring that's subsequently causing the strange behavior, in whatever browser you're using to test, verify you have the debug player installed at the bottom of this page: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/find-version-flash-player.html

Comment: strange indeed. I tried to run the application in both Chrome and IE and the strange behaviour manifested itself on both counts. I would try to install the debug version of flash player and see whether it leads me to something.

Comment: Yah Chrome internally manages updating it's own version of flash player, believe there's a couple of steps to make that work, otherwise for windows install flash debug player in IE by getting the ActiveX plugin for other browsers get the netscape-compatible plugin, or if on mac get the debug plugin for mac.

Comment: Was able to resolve this by updating the flash plugin. For some reason, the update on the Chrome browser was like stopped.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution to this issue was to update the FlashPlayer to the latest version in Chrome.